# Jolt transformation from flow file

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

I have a flow file with the content file as below

```
{
"name" :"aaa",
"address": "address line1",
"pincode": "pincode",
"mobile": "mobile",
"State" " "state"
}
```

I wanted to make an output which should be as below

```
 {
  "details": "primary details",
  "home":[
  {
    "name": "name",
    "address": "address",
    "mobile": "mobile",
    }
 ],
  "state": "state"
}
```

could anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 3):

How about this jolt spec:

getting all the values for **name,address,pincode,mobile,State** keys and adding **default** key/value for **details**, But not sure how to keep **default details** key/value in first position

```
    [{
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
        "name": "home[0].name",
        "address": "home[0].address",
        "mobile": "home[0].mobile",
        "State": "state"
    }
}, {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
        "details": "prirmay details"
    }
}]
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "home": [{
        "name": "aaa",
        "address": "address line1",
        "mobile": "mobile"
    }],
    "state": "state",
    "details": "prirmay details"
}
```

If you want to keep some default values for **name,address** keys then use this jolt spec:

```
[{
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
        "mobile": "home[0].mobile",
        "State": "state"
    }
}, {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
        "details": "primary details",
        "home[]": {
            "*": {
        "name": "name",
        "address":"address"
            }
        }
    }
}]
```

**Output:**

```
 {
    "home": [{
        "mobile": "mobile",
        "name": "name",
        "address": "address"
    }],
    "state": "state",
    "details": "primary details"
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The first spec was enough for me.